# Is this unknown character meant to be an allusion to a Six?

Tags: character, reference, westworld-tv, battlestar-galactica

While recently rewatching the HBO re-imaged TV series, *Westworld*, I noticed in the second season two episode titled, Reunion, the camera follows the back of this character dressed in a white dress with wavy platinum blonde hair, who briefly glances at Dolores playing the piano, as she walks by and heads for the terrace.

[image: Party Reunion]

While we never see the character's face, nor does the show fixate on her again, there is a familiarity in her appearance (Height, Hair, Style of Dress, movement/gate) to that of the re-imaged *Battlestar Galactica's* Six, whether it be Caprica or Messenger Six...

[image: BSG Caprica]

So my question is, *is this an intentional reference to the BSG character(s) and does it hold any other significance outside of the "meta" amusement of: androids looking at other androids or could it imply that there is something bigger in the Westworld-universe than humans and AI?*

Comment: Now you mention it, I think I had the same association, but brushed it off as being purely coincidental. It does indeed make sense as a nod, however.

Comment: you might thing that a blonde in white dress is some kind of trope in general. For  example for mysterious womens. Who we never learn much about. And you would be right. It's a trope.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY And here I thought the standard trope involved a woman in a [*red* dress](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Woman_in_Red) :P

Comment: @Steve-O we have tropes for everything. Especially when they are so old they were present in arthurian legends https://allthetropes.org/wiki/Woman_in_White

Comment: And now that I have caught up to the first episode of S3, I'm more convinced this was intentional, as Dolores plot with Liam is very similar with Caprica Six (character) manipulating Gaius to get access to Caprica's (planet) defense mainframe. Liam even has a similar look to Gaius, although the actor plays straight up drama, where Callis was very comedic.

Comment: Though a very good catch, it could be indirectly linked, i.e. a textbook beauty with a simple white dress to suggest artificiality (as you'd expect the first humanlike robots to be beautiful humans). Unsure if we can find confirmation on it being a direct reference or an overlap in similar themes being visualized.

Comment: @Flater, It does work as a double reference, I just think that the BSG connection is so strong, given the season 3 opener as well, that I think it kind of outweighs it, because it's more significant, but I agree, I probably not going to get a confirmation from the EPs/etc anytime soon, but thought maybe there was one I missed.